# How to improve performance when using union with jsonb_query_path function

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, union, jsonb

I have a PostgreSQL ( version 13.6 ) table containing a jsonb column

As a solution to [Getting attributes from different paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74354332/how-to-select-jsonb-attribute-in-different-paths-in-separate-rows) question I had asked,  I am trying to use union on the querying the 3 pairs of paths separately and using the union to get the complete data set.  Whereas each of the 3 individual queries is taking a few milliseconds ( in the range of 80ms to 170ms ) when I run the query with the union, it takes between 50 seconds and a minute.  I have to do the union, because this is a query for creating a view which should have all the data satisfying the criteria in the individual query.

The json structure is like below ( The actual jsons are more than 4000 lines long ) and the table has about 200k rows

```
{
    "node1": { 
        "node2": { 
            "node3": [ 
                {
                    "node4": { 
                        "node5": { 
                            "Code": "34",
                            "Image": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
                            "System": "2",
                            "PercentageAddup": "True"
                        }
                    },
                    "node6": { 
                        "RoleID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000033",
                        "UserID": "WebServices",
                        "PartyID": "cc6ef1d8-d0ad-4044-9bd8-6c34c16eec5f",
                        "Percentage": "1.00"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "node4": { 
                        "node5": { 
                            "Code": "32",
                            "Image": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
                            "System": "2",
                            "PercentageAddup": "False"
                        }
                    },
                    "node6": { 
                        "RoleID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000118",
                        "UserID": "WebServices",
                        "PartyID": "10d8e781-a4d7-4a17-a4a0-eb7ac71b75b4",
                        "Percentage": "1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "node7": [ 
            {
                "node8": { 
                    "node9": { 
                        "Code": "8",
                        "Image": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
                        "System": "2",
                        "PercentageAddup": "True"
                    }
                },
                "node10": { 
                    "RoleID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000143",
                    "UserID": "WebServices",
                    "PartyID": "10d8e781-a4d7-4a17-a4a0-eb7ac71b75b4",
                    "Relationship": "Self"
                }
            },
            {
                "node8": { 
                    "node9": { 
                        "Code": "31",
                        "Image": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
                        "System": "2",
                        "PercentageAddup": "False"
                    }
                },
                "node10": { 
                    "RoleID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000156",
                    "UserID": "WebServices",
                    "PartyID": "10d8e781-a4d7-4a17-a4a0-eb7ac71b75b4",
                    "Relationship": "Self"
                }
            }
        ],
        "node11": { 
            "node12": { 
                "node13": { 
                    "Code": "38",
                    "Image": "ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff",
                    "System": "2",
                    "PercentageAddup": "False"
                }
            },
            "node14": { 
                "RoleID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000170",
                "UserID": "WebServices",
                "Percentage": "1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The union query looks like below

```
   select polnum,
      codepath1->>'Code' as code,
      pid_path1->>'PartyID' as party_id
   from(
         select polnum,
            jsonb_path_query(
               payload,
               '$.node1[*].node2[*].node3[*].node4[*].node5[*]'
            ) as codepath1,
            jsonb_path_query(
               payload,
               '$.node1[*].node2[*].node3[*].node6[*]'
            ) as pid_path1
         from json_table
      ) sub1
   union
   select polnum,
      codepath2->>'Code' as code,
      pid_path2->>'PartyID' as party_id
   from(
         select polnum,
            jsonb_path_query(
               payload,
               '$.node1[*].node7[*].node8[*].node9[*]'
            ) as codepath2,
            jsonb_path_query(
               payload,
               '$.node1[*].node7[*].node10[*]'
            ) as pid_path2
         from json_table
      ) sub2
   union
   select polnum,
      codepath3->>'Code' as code,
      pid_path3->>'PartyID' as party_id
   from(
         select polnum,
            jsonb_path_query(
               payload,
               '$.node1[*].node11[*].node12[*].node13[*]'
            ) as codepath3,
            jsonb_path_query(
               payload,
               '$.node1[*].node11[*].node14[*]'
            ) as pid_path3
         from json_table
      ) sub3
```

How can I improve the performance when using the Union?  Or is there a way to do the query without using the `union` that will help the performance?

**Update - Added EXPLAIN Plan**

```
Unique  (cost=1266592.80..1272296.78 rows=380265 width=138) (actual time=30354.491..30910.817 rows=530882 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=2271534, temp read=6422 written=6443
  ->  Sort  (cost=1266592.80..1267543.46 rows=380265 width=138) (actual time=30354.489..30775.806 rows=532900 loops=1)
        Sort Key: subsel1.polnum, subsel1.lob, subsel1.eventoccurredtime, ((subsel1.codepatha ->> 'Code'::text)), ((subsel1.partyidpatha ->> 'PartyID'::text))
        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 37256kB
        Buffers: shared hit=2271534, temp read=6422 written=6443
        ->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..1176755.61 rows=380265 width=138) (actual time=0.585..28253.046 rows=532900 loops=1)
              Workers Planned: 2
              Workers Launched: 2
              Buffers: shared hit=2271534
              ->  Parallel Append  (cost=0.00..1137729.11 rows=269355 width=138) (actual time=0.250..23892.726 rows=177633 loops=3)
                    Buffers: shared hit=2271534
                    ->  Subquery Scan on subsel1  (cost=0.00..377526.56 rows=126755 width=85) (actual time=0.222..12559.211 rows=131748 loops=2)
                          Buffers: shared hit=757198
                          ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..375625.24 rows=74562000 width=85) (actual time=0.219..12453.920 rows=131748 loops=2)
                                Buffers: shared hit=757198
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on json_table fp  (cost=0.00..2069.62 rows=74562 width=42) (actual time=0.004..25.233 rows=63138 loops=2)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=1324
                    ->  Subquery Scan on subsel2  (cost=0.00..377526.56 rows=126755 width=85) (actual time=0.214..12306.081 rows=101788 loops=2)
                          Buffers: shared hit=757198
                          ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..375625.24 rows=74562000 width=85) (actual time=0.211..12252.180 rows=101788 loops=2)
                                Buffers: shared hit=757198
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on json_table fp_1  (cost=0.00..2069.62 rows=74562 width=42) (actual time=0.004..26.024 rows=63138 loops=2)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=1324
                    ->  Subquery Scan on subsel3  (cost=0.00..377526.56 rows=126755 width=85) (actual time=0.176..21849.856 rows=65829 loops=1)
                          Buffers: shared hit=757138
                          ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..375625.24 rows=74562000 width=85) (actual time=0.173..21797.195 rows=65829 loops=1)
                                Buffers: shared hit=757138
                                ->  Parallel Seq Scan on json_table fp_2  (cost=0.00..2069.62 rows=74562 width=42) (actual time=0.010..34.069 rows=126277 loops=1)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=1324
Planning Time: 0.178 ms
Execution Time: 30949.884 ms
```

**Update 2 - Single query Explain Plan**

```
Subquery Scan on subsel1  (cost=1000.00..391202.06 rows=126755 width=85) (actual time=0.433..10203.467 rows=263496 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=757198
->  Gather  (cost=1000.00..389300.74 rows=126755 width=85) (actual time=0.430..10095.102 rows=263496 loops=1)
      Workers Planned: 1
      Workers Launched: 1
      Buffers: shared hit=757198
      ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..375625.24 rows=74562000 width=85) (actual time=0.234..8649.662 rows=131748 loops=2)
            Buffers: shared hit=757198
            ->  Parallel Seq Scan on json_table fp  (cost=0.00..2069.62 rows=74562 width=42) (actual time=0.006..12.867 rows=63138 loops=2)
                  Buffers: shared hit=1324
Planning Time: 0.073 ms
Execution Time: 10221.966 ms
```

Thank you

Comment: I need to remove duplicates, hence using union.  Is there a better option?  Also, since I could not put actual jsons, I tried to create the sample here.  I will try to run the quey and make the necessary corrections.  Also, will run the EXPLAIN and include it

Comment: Your new plan with just one leg of the UNION is taking 10 seconds, which is far longer than the initially reported  80ms to 170ms.  So the problem must not be with the UNION, but with some other difference in how the query is written.

Comment: I just ran that same single query without including the EXPLAIN part and this is what I got in dBeaver output window : `200 row(s) fetched - 83ms (2ms fetch), on 2022-11-11 at 22:15:27`.  I don't know, how or if the addition of EXPLAIN affects the actual execution, but it did come back in 83ms

Comment: 200 rows is a lot less than what your plans show.  I think your client tool must be automatically adding a LIMIT 200 (or using a cursor).  That explains it, as the UNION plan needs to read to completion anyway due to deduplication while without the UNION it can stop early.

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense.  So, is there any way I can change my query and still get the unique (de-duped ) rows, more efficiently?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the deduplication is not the problem.  Not having deduplication allows your client to plays tricks on you, making it seem much faster than it really is.  But if you really do want all the rows and not just the first 200, then this isn't actually fast to get all of the rows, even without the dedup.  I don't know how to extrapolate the one value you show up to 4000 lines so that I can test with that, but I think you probably need to refactor your data to be more normalized if you want to get better performance.

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying to read on indices on JSONB in Postgresql.  Do you think, I should look at creating indices on code and partyid on each of the paths?  I am not familiar yet about these indices, but I am trying to read up on it and hence wondering if you could comment on it

Comment: Since most of your rows seems to contribute something to the output, I don't see how an index could help.  An index can help it identify which rows it needs to inspect, but you need to inspect nearly all of them.  Maybe a materialized view would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks.  I will work with DBAs to get an MV created - I don't have access to create objects in the DB - need to provide the script to DBAs.  One other question, if you don't mind.  When I was trying to read up on indices, one of the SO question had a comment on - `CREATE INDEX ON publishers((info->>'name'));`   It said  `The double-parentheses are also important.`   Could you explain why?